# send value from servlet to javascript error (japanese character)

Tags: javascript, java, character-encoding, special-characters

i got error when string "ああああ" become "????" then pass data from servlet to javascript.

controller .java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "searchbook", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain")
    public @ResponseBody String myController(HttpServletRequest request) throws SQLException {
        String myItem = request.getParameter("searchid");

        PostgrConnect db = new PostgrConnect();
        ResultSet rs;
        Book book = new Book();

        try {
            rs = db.getData("select * from mt_book where book_id='" + myItem + "'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                book.setBook_id(rs.getString("book_id"));
                book.setBook_title(rs.getString("book_title"));
                book.setAuthor_name(rs.getString("author_name"));
                book.setPublisher(rs.getString("publisher"));
                book.setPublication_day(rs.getString("publication_day"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return book.getBook_id() + ";" + book.getBook_title() + ";" + book.getAuthor_name() + ";" + book.getPublisher()
                + ";" + book.getPublication_day();
    }
```

javascript

```
function Search() {
    if (checkInputSearch() == "true") {
    var date = "";
    var searchid = document.getElementById("bookid").value;
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "searchbook",
        data : {
        searchid : searchid
        },
        success : function(html) {
        var res = html.split(";");
        if (res[0] == "null") {
            alert(MSG0000 + " " + bookid.value + " " + MSG0004);
            Clear();
        } else {
            alert(MSG0003);
            document.getElementById("bookid").value = res[0];
            document.getElementById("booktitle").value = res[1];
            document.getElementById("authorname").value = res[2];
            document.getElementById("publishher").value = res[3];
            date = res[4].split("-");
            document.getElementById("day").value = date[2];
            document.getElementById("month").value = date[1];
            document.getElementById("year").value = date[0];
        }
        },
        error : function(e) {
        alert(MSG0005);
        console.log("Error:" + e);
        }
    });
    }

}
```

i can get data from database :

http://imgur.com/fpibNPt

but when pass to javascript :

http://imgur.com/WhGwKwP

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the following:

1. Java file is encoded as MS932
2. The response/request is encoded as Shift_JIS
3. The front-end HTML has meta tag defined with charset as Shift_JIS

If you are using Eclipse IDE, for Java File encoding, right click on file name in navigation pane, click Properties.
[image: Open Properties Dialog in Eclipse IDE]

Select "Text file encoding" > select "Other" and then type MS932
[image: Set Encoding]

This will work.
2 years ago I was working for a Pfizer Japan and at the very beginning of the development phase we faced these challenges.

Comment: i cant find how to encode java file to MS932 . can you show me how ?

Comment: Updated my answer with demo on how to set encoding for Java file

Comment: i tried that way but it's still not work for me.
i encoded that string with base64 and decode it in javascript